# Solve for $x$ in $\log_x2=\log_3x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Solve for $x$ in $\log_x2=\log_3x$

What did I do wrong in my attempt?
$$\log_x2=\log_3x$$
$$\dfrac{\log2}{\log x}=\dfrac{\log x}{\log3}$$
$$\log^2x=\log2\log3$$
$$\pm\log x=\sqrt{\log2\log3}$$
$$x=\pm10^\sqrt{\log2\log3}$$

Comment: On the last line the $\pm$ goes in the exponent.

Comment: If you have $\pm\log_{10} A = B$ that doesn't become $A = \pm10^B,$ but rather $\log_{10} A = \pm B$ and then $A =10^{\pm B}. \qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $$\pm \log_a(x) = \sqrt{\log_a(2)\log_a(3)} \implies \log_a(x) = \pm\sqrt{\log_a(2)\log_a(3)} \implies x = a^{\pm \sqrt{\log_a(2)\log_a(3)}}.$$

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that if you use a base other than $10$ here it works just as well; for example $9^{\pm \sqrt{\log_92\cdot\log_93}}$ is the same as $10^{\pm\sqrt{\log_{10} 2 \cdot \log_{10} 3}}. \qquad$

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy. Updated the post.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks